# Inverse of a $G$-equivariant map

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $X$ a set that has a transitive left action. I am trying to show that $A := \{f: X \rightarrow X: f(g.x) = g.f(x)\}$ is a group. The only thing I'm having trouble showing is that every element of $A$ has an inverse.

My idea is as follows: Pick $f \in A$ and fix $x_{1} \in X$. I want to construct an "$f^{-1}$". Since $f$ acts on $X$, $f(x_{1}) = g_{1}.x_{1}$ for some $g_{1} \in G$. Since the action on $X$ is transitive, for any $x_{2} \in X$, there exists an $h$ such that $x_{1} = h.x_{2}$. Let $g_{2}$ be such that $f(x_{2}) = g_{2}.x_{2}$. Then
$$g_{1}.x_{1} = f(x_{1}) = f(h.x_{2}) = h.f(x_{2}) = (hg_{2}).x_{2} = (hg_{2}h^{-1}).x_{1}$$
and hence $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are conjugates. Then $\{hg_{1}h^{-1}: h \in G\}$ is a collection of elements of $G$ which "represent" $f$ in the sense that for each $x \in X$, $f(x) = a.x$ and $a \in \{hg_{1}h^{-1}: h \in G\}$. Since $G$ is finite, so is $\{hg_{1}h^{-1}: h \in G\}$, but how I am to use this to construct an $F: X \rightarrow X$ such that $F(g.x) = g.F(x)$ and $F \circ f = \textrm{id}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose an fix an element $\;x_0\in X\;$ , then for any $\;x\in X\;$ there exists $\;g_x\in G\;$ s.t. $\;x=g_xx_0\;$

Also fix $\;y_0:=f^{-1}(x_0)\;$ , and define

$$h:X\to X\;,\;\;h(x)=g_xy_0$$

Then

$$h(gx)=h((gg_x)x_0):=gg_xy_0=gh(x)\implies h\in A\;,\;\;\text{and}$$

$$f\circ h(x)=f(h(x)):=f(g_xy_0)=g_xf(y_0)=g_xx_0=x$$

Comment: So why is $h$ well defined? Presumably, I could have $x = g_{x_{1}}x_{0}$ and $x = g_{x_{2}}x_{0}$ and this could lead to 2 different potential $h$.